# Please explain the output of this class constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class tricie
{
public:
    tricie(int);
    ~tricie();
    void acc();
    void deacc();
private:
    int df_speed=8;
};

tricie::tricie(int speed_input)                //Shouldn't this make the speed=8?
{
    int speed;
    if (speed_input > df_speed)
    {
        speed=speed_input;
        cout<<"speed now is "<<speed<<" km/hr \n";
    }
    else
    {
        speed=df_speed;
        cout<<"speed now is "<<speed<<" km/hr \n";
    }
}
tricie::~tricie()
{

}
void tricie::acc()
{
    int speed=(speed+1);
    cout<<"speed now is "<<speed<<" km/hr \n";
}
void tricie::deacc()
{
    int speed=(speed-1);
    cout<<"speed now is "<<speed<<" km/hr \n";
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])  //Xcode but these stuff in the bracket (ignore)
{
    tricie biker1(4);          //If i put any number > 8 the program work correctly
    biker1.acc();              //output from this line is "speed now is 5 km/hr "    instead of 9
    biker1.deacc();            //output from this line is "speed now is 4 km/hr "    instead of 8
    biker1.deacc();            //output from this line is "speed now is 3 km/hr "    instead of 7
    return 0;
}
```

I want to know if I am missing a concept which tells me why the output 8 5 4 3  not 8 9 8 7?

Thanks in advance and sorry if the question is stupid i am teaching myself using sams teach yourself c++ in 24 hrs book.

Thanks everyone for the quick response i will search if there is a way to prevent compiling in these cases put i have a follow up question:                                                  When I put int speed in the private part of the class and it is working fine but i want to know is there another error i am not getting since i put it in the private part of the class and the main function can see it?

Comment: Your constructor is setting the value of `speed`, which is a local variable. As soon as it returns `speed` goes out of scope, which makes the whole affair pointless. Did you mean to set `df_speed` instead? Your other methods also refer to a local variable `speed`, which is wrong as well.

Comment: Note that you will **not** learn C++ in 24 hours :)

Comment: int speed=(speed+1); compile? I dont see a member or a global speed.

Comment: @qPCR4vir: It does compile, since variable names are available immediately after their declaration, before any initialiser, but gives undefined behaviour since it's initialised with its own, uninitialised, value.

Comment: @Mike Seymour  Ok.. I see.. what a problem ! Thank!

Answer (score 2):

There's something wrong with your basic concept, because you're using local variables (`int speed`) that will lose their value once you leave functions. What you'll most likely want is a member variable (just like `df_speed`).

The output in your constructor is correct, because you set the value either way.

However, the output of `tricie::acc()` and `tricie::deacc()` is undefined, as you're using uninitialized variables (`speed`) in assignments/calculations.

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your code. You redeclare the `speed` variable in all of your functions (constructor, `acc()` and `deacc()`), for example in `deacc()`:

```
int speed=(speed+1);
```

Initially `speed` in undeclared (in this scope), but you use it to subtract `1` from it. Which is (totally) undefined behavior.

To fix this, remove the variable declarations (`int`) in these 3 situations and add a class variable to the class to store the current speed:

```
class tricie {
  //...
  int speed;
  //...
}

void tricie::deacc()
{
    speed=(speed-1);
    cout<<"speed now is "<<speed<<" km/hr \n";
}
```

Same for `acc()` and in the constructor remove `int speed;` completely.

Note: I do not know what `df_speed` is, I assume(d) 'default speed'. If it is the class variable that should hold the *actual* speed, you need to rename all `speed` variable usages to `df_speed`. But this depending on the meaning of `df_speed` (which is probably described in your book..?)

Comment: @qPCR4vir Well assuming the OP compiled the application (to notice the output was wrong), it is undefined! :)

Comment: I put int speed in the private part of the class and it is working fine but i want to know is there another error i am not getting since i put it in the private part of the class and the main function can see it?

Comment: If you put it in the private part of the class, it is unavailable from scopes *outside* of the class (for example, the 'main scope') If you need to get hold of the value, create a so called 'getter'. This is a public function that returns the value of the private variable. This is useful, as the variable cannot get modified from the 'outside' but still can be read. If there are more things unclear (about other C++ topics), please open a new question!

Comment: Thank u very much u were very helpful these 2 parts weren't explained in detail in my book.